# Set type of a variable using a condition

Tags: .net, vb.net, generics, types, late-binding

How to set type of a variable using a condition? 
If I do like example below, my variable `x` is no more existing after the end if, here is my problem.

```
    If RequestedType = "Integer" Then
        Dim x As Integer
    Else
        Dim x As String
    End If
```

Comment: _Why_ do you think you want to do this?

Comment: your declaration is valid, you can use `x` as `string` as well as `integer` since they are in different **scope**.

Comment: I have 2 similar functions doing the exact same actions: extract a value of a datatable according some parameters. But in first case data are integer and in 2nd case data are string. So currently I have 2 time the almost same function, one if type of column of interest is integer and one if type of column of interest is String

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such possibility. You would rather use the [Overloading of Methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973896.aspx).
I guess that you would do some processing with `x`. For example, you could have a call to an overloaded subroutine making the processing on `x`.

```
Function ProcessMe(ByVal p_X As String) As Integer ' I assume you would return an Integer...
    ' Write here the processing on parameter p_X
End Function

Function ProcessMe(ByVal p_X As Integer) As Integer
    ' Call the previous method with p_X converted to string
    Return ProcessMe(p_X.ToString())
End Function
```

Then, in your code you coud write

```
If RequestedType = "Integer" Then
    Dim x As Integer
    ProcessMe(x)
Else
    Dim x As String
    ProcessMe(x)
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

use `Dim` only to declare the variable instead. it will automatically set to  the type of value that you are assigning;

```
Dim x=10 '<--- here x is an integer type
Dim y="10"'<-- here y is of type string
Dim z=10.362'<-- here z is of type double
```

if you declare as you said in the question, your declaration is valid, you can use `x` as `string` as well as `integer` since they are in different scope.

Answer (score 0):

You could declare a method that accepts a generic return type which you define when you call it.

Something like this:

```
Public Function GetDbValue(Of T)() As T
    Dim value As T = CType(GetYourValueHere, T)
    Return value
End Function
```

The  you can call it like this:

```
Dim s As String = GetDbValue(Of String)()
```

or

```
Dim i As Integer = GetDbValue(Of Integer)()
```

Answer (score -3):

```
    Dim x    
    If RequestedType = "Integer" Then
        x = 0
    Else
        x = ""
    End If
```

Comment: The type of x is Object, not an integer or string.

Comment: Unless the poster tells us what exactly has in mind, it is perfectly valid declaration and assignment. His only problem on his example is that the scope of x is valid only within the if...then

Comment: It doesn't compile (at least with Option Strict On), so in my book it is far from perfectly valid

Comment: It does actually compile on default settings on VS2015.